# AutoLisp - Determining the number and value ​of block attributes

Tags: lisp, autocad, autolisp

I have to write the function that determines the number and values ​​of block attributes in lisp. I do not have any idea for this. Could you help me?

Comment: AutoLisp or Common Lisp? They're not the same dialect.

Comment: @Barmar AutoLisp, I corrected it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70735718/autolisp-two-basic-functions-determining-the-number-and-value-of-block-attri

Answer (score 0):

Does the software that your using not have an attribute out function that can be typed into the command line like [ATTOUT](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-899B195A-EFF0-4AEC-B0F8-7444EC75D649-htm.html)? If so, then try opening the file with a spreadsheet application, like Excel.